# Proper steps for translating from CSV file in magento

Tags: csv, enterprise-1.14, transaction

I want to translate some text using CSV file by going through following steps.

1. Created CSV file named "**Mynamspace_Mymodule.csv**" in **app/locale/en_US/** and feeded it with my translations like, "text to translate", "translated text"
2. Then added the following xml in config.xml of my Module under **frontend** tag.

> ```
> <translate>
>         <modules>
>             <Mynamspace_Mymodule>
>                 <files>
>                     <default>Mynamspace_Mymodule.csv</default>
>                 </files>
>             </Mynamspace_Mymodule>
>         </modules>
>     </translate>
> ```

3. Then I tried to translate my text like,

> echo Mage::helper('Mynamspace_Mymodule')->__("text to translate");

and it returned the following error.

Class 'Mage_Mynamspace_Mymodule_Helper_Data' not found in app/Mage.php on line **547**

Please help!

Comment: Where you declared helper class in your `config.xml`?

Comment: Sir, under `<global>` tag.

Comment: Could you add in your question?

Comment: `<helpers>
            <api>
                <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Helper</class>
            </api>
        </helpers>`

Comment: Sir But I didn't added any logic for translation in my helper class, because I don't know what to add there for translation.

Comment: That's why I want to know, how can I translate my text using CSV file in magento, step-wise.

Answer (score 0):

First off all, try this one in `config.xml` for **Helper class not found** error.

```
<global>
    ...........

    <helpers>
        <mynamspace_mymodule>
            <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Helper</class>
        </mynamspace_mymodule>
    </helpers>
    ...........
</global>
```

Then just have look this articale [How to add your own translations to Extensions?](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-your-own-translations-to-custom-modules/)

Comment: Sir I have tried the method in article, and the change you mentioned but didn't solved the problem. Any way Sir I am really delighted.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my own question with a little help from Supravat Sir. I will describe it here Step by Step.

1. Created CSV file named "Mynamspace_Mymodule.csv" in app/locale/en_US/ and feeded it with my translations like, "text to translate", "translated text". Make sure you have selected **English(United States)** from Locale Dropdown at your StoreView configuration at **System>Configuration>General>locale Options>**. Use a simple editor for your CSV file for convenience, I used **Sublime Text 3**.
2. Then added the following xml in `config.xml` of my Module under frontend tag.

`<frontend>
    ..........
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <Mynamspace_Mymodule>
                <files>
                    <default>Mynamspace_Mymodule.csv</default>
                </files>
            </Mynamspace_Mymodule>
        </modules>
    </translate>
</frontend>`

3. Then added the following in my module's `config.xml` file.

   ```
   <global>
   ...........

   <helpers>
       <mynamspace_mymodule>
           <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Helper</class>
       </mynamspace_mymodule>
   </helpers>
   ...........
   ```
4. Then I translated my text like,

   `echo Mage::helper('mymodule')->__("text to translate");`

**Note:** First letter of your **module** must be in lowercase as 'mymodule', above in `Mage::helper('')` method.

Tis done.